# How to convert array s from JSON file to java object

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with two different arrays. I need to convert it into java objects. Is there any method to do it using GSON and JSON. This is what we have tried.

```
    package package1;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class foo
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            String jsonInput = "{\"JObjects\":{\"JArray1\":[{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\"},{\"A\":\"a1\",\"B\":\"b2\",\"C\":\"c3\",\"D\":\"d4\",\"E\":\"e5\"},{\"A\":\"aa\",\"B\":\"bb\",\"C\":\"cc\",\"D\":\"dd\"}]}}";
            JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
            JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("JObjects");
            JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("JArray1");
            for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray);
                    System.out.printf("%d ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:\n", elementNames.length);
                    for (String elementName : elementNames)
                        {
                            String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
                            System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                }
        }
    }
```

PLease guide me with the code.

Comment: "PLease guide me with the entire code" is not the right way of asking questions; an example input with expected output is the least ... even better if you have already tried to do something, we don't provide copy & paste code on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse json objects to java objects and and vice-versa. To do so, you can use Google's framework 'gson': http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

**Maven dependency**

> <dependency>
>   
>      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
>   
>      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
>   
>      <version>2.2.4</version>
>   
> </dependency>

**EXAMPLE:**

We make a java model class 'Person'. That person has a first name and a last name:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    //getters and setters
    ...

    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstname: "+ firstname + ", lastname: " + lastname + "]";
    }
}
```

Now we can create a person object and parse it to a json string with gson:

```
public class PersonToJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstname("Laurent");
        person.setLastname("Hinoul");

        String json = gson.toJson(person);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

**The output will be: {"firstname":"Laurent","lastname":"Hinoul"}**

Now we can easily parse that string back to an object:

```
public class JsonToPerson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String json = "{"firstname":"Laurent","lastname":"Hinoul"}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

**The output will be: Person [firstname: Laurent, lastname: Hinoul]**